# How and when to create a new JwtConsumerBuilder when keys in the HttpsJwks cache have gone stale

Tags: jwt, jose4j

This question is in regards to the jose4j JWT library.  I am planning to create a single `JwtConsumerBuilder` instance for processing all incoming requests.  I read here on stackoverflow and in release notes that JwtConsumerBuilder is multi-thread safe.  I also plan to use the  `setVerificationKey` method to validate the signature.  When the key expires, I assume I will get an exception.  Which type of exception will be returned: `InvalidJwtSignatureException` or `InvalidKeyException`?

When such an exception occurs, my plan is to update my global instance of the JwtConsumerBuilder with a new instance after retrieving the updated key through the class `HttpsJwksVerificationKeyResolver`.  Is this a sound approach or does the resolver take care of this for me.

Comment: In reading the code in `resolveKey` of class `HttpsJwksVerificationKeyResolver` it looks like this scenario is handled. So the extra coding is not needed.  

`theChosenOne = verificationJwkSelector.select(jws, jsonWebKeys);
            if (theChosenOne == null)
            {
                httpsJkws.refresh();
`

Comment: Yes, HttpsJwksVerificationKeyResolver is intended to handle rotation of the keys at the JWKS endpoint (based on the Key ID in the header of the JWT).